# A way around F1 score calculation when recall and precision is zero in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, plotly, data-science, metrics

I am trying to create an plotly graph that plots f1 scores per epoch epochs. I have a function that calculates F1 scores but sometimes, my model's recall and precision will hit zero on a random epoch. This subsequently means that the whole F1 score becomes zero. How can I circumvent this issue? Is there a placeholder value I can put down or does that plot just go to zero? How could I code that in python?

Code:

```
precision_nums = [0.5146262049674988,
                  0.6140350699424744, 0.0, 0.6796116232872009, 0.5716332197189331, 0.7028985619544983,
                  0.7329059839248657, 0.7030965685844421, 0.709796667098999, 0.6807432174682617, 0.708791196346283,
                  0.7094972133636475, 0.7105262875556946, 0.7118958830833435, 0.7184466123580933, 0.7184466123580933,
                  0.7025089859962463]

recall_nums = [0.5146262049674988,
               0.6140350699424744, 0.0, 0.6796116232872009, 0.5716332197189331, 0.7028985619544983,
               0.7329059839248657, 0.7030965685844421, 0.709796667098999, 0.6807432174682617, 0.708791196346283,
               0.7094972133636475, 0.7105262875556946, 0.7118958830833435, 0.7184466123580933, 0.7184466123580933,
               0.7025089859962463]


def f1_score_computation(precision, recall):
    f1_score_list = []
    for (precision_score, recall_score) in zip(precision, recall):
        f1_score_list.append(2 * ((precision_score * recall_score) / (precision_score + recall_score)))
    return f1_score_list


f1_score_computation(precision_nums, recall_nums)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the exception yourself.

```
def f1_score_computation(precision, recall):
    f1_score_list = []
    for (precision_score, recall_score) in zip(precision, recall):
        try:
            f1_score_list.append(2 * ((precision_score * recall_score) / (precision_score + recall_score)))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            f1_score_list.append(np.nan)
    return f1_score_list
```

This will return `np.nan` whenever you hit division by zero. Plotting libraries handles `nan` fine.
[image: plotting with nan]

Comment: np.nan huh, that is definitely new to me. Thanks a bunch